# How do I skip language selection with installation profile?

Tags: users, installation

I am building an installation profile for Drupal 7 and trying to skip the language selection page.

In the .profile file I put the following code:

```
function efocus_install_tasks_alter(&$tasks, $install_state){
    $tasks['install_select_locale']['run'] = INSTALL_TASK_SKIP;
    $install_state['parameters']['locale'] = 'en';
}
```

This skips the page but apperantly the locale selection is not working for some reason. Anybody that has any experience with this? I am quite new to Drupal, just started a month ago and can't figure out why it is not working. Any tips on what I can try?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This cannot work, because $install_state is passed as value, not as reference. So changing it has no effects.

```
function efocus_install_tasks_alter(&$tasks, $install_state){
    $tasks['install_select_locale']['function'] = '_efocus_locale_selection';
}

// local callback function
function _efocus_locale_selection(&$install_state){
    $install_state['parameters']['locale'] = 'en';
}
```

This one works. I am simply replacing the standard_locale_selection with a custom function, which gets the install_state passed as reference. So i can change the value...

Comment: It did work thanks to the answer of pico34, the global did the trick. Thanks for your answer anyway!

Comment: What you should really do is pass the variable to the function instead of using a global at all.

If you take a look at the system.api.php line 3835 you see, that my code is from a demo case of hook_install_tasks_alter(). The way it is intended to be. The other solution is just a "quick fix". Anyway... do whatever you like ;)

Comment: Thanks for the extra explanation. I did use your answer to edit other parts of the installation process so I will use the same for the locale to be consistent.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works, you just missed : `global`

```
function efocus_install_tasks_alter(&$tasks, $install_state){
  global $install_state;

  $tasks['install_select_locale']['display'] = FALSE;
  $tasks['install_select_locale']['run'] = INSTALL_TASK_SKIP;
  $install_state['parameters']['locale'] = 'en';

}
```